# Generate dates based on 2 different ranges

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df with columns :

```
Date_1  count
01/09/2019  5
02/09/2019  4
03/09/2019  5
04/09/2019  6
05/09/2019  7
06/09/2019  8
07/09/2019  10
08/09/2019  9
09/09/2019  11
10/09/2019  12
11/09/2019  13
12/09/2019  14
13/09/2019  15
14/09/2019  18
15/09/2019  17
16/09/2019  18
17/09/2019  19
18/09/2019  20
19/09/2019  21
20/09/2019  22
21/09/2019  23
22/09/2019  24
23/09/2019  25
24/09/2019  26
25/09/2019  27
26/09/2019  28
27/09/2019  29
28/09/2019  30
29/09/2019  30
30/09/2019  30
```

I want to generate df2 having 3 columns date_1, count, date_2 such that :

date_2 is generated based on count. if the count for a date_1 is 5, then there would be 5 entries in the dataframe. Also date_2 has the constraint that :

1. 70% of the values are in the range of (date_1 - 10 to date_1 - 2)
2. rest values are in the range of (date_1 - 30 to date_1 - 11)

Also each of the date_1 and date_2 should be unique tuple i.e. no pair (date_1,date_2) is repeated.

For example :

for the first row : 
4 values for date_1 should be in the range of range1 =  (01/09/2019 - 10 = 22/08/2019 to 01/09/2019 - 30/08/2019) and rest 1 value should be in the range of range 2(01/09/2019 - 30 = 02/08/2019 to 01/09/2019 - 21/08/2019).

for the values in the dataframe where count = 30, we don't need to make this change as we need unique values and since the total values that date_2 can take is 30, we have to incorporate all the values. (we can't go with 70% and 30% in that scenario)

I am not able to understand how to particularly design that dataframe based on these factors. So, for count >11, it should have all values in the range 1(8 values). before that, its the 70% and 30% division in range 1 and range 2.

Can anyone help me in defining these constraints.

Thanks

Comment: The requirement that 70% of the values of *date_2* should be in the range of *(date_1 - 10 to date_1 - 2)* and they are to be unique is in some cases impossible to meet.
E.g. for *28/09/2019* you want *30* output rows.
70 % of them is **21** and the days to choose from are only **9** dates.
Maybe in this case repetitions should be allowed?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo like I mentioned in the question as well, in those cases 9 dates are to be present and rest needs to be from the range of other. Like I mentioned, the case where 30 is the count, then between 1 month range we need to provide. We do not need repititions in any case for date_1, date_2

Answer (score 0):

The first function to define is:

```
def getSample(rng, n):
    siz = rng.size
    return rng.sample(n = n, replace = n > siz)
```

It returns a sample of *n* elements from *rng*.
If it is possible (the required number of elements is less or equal
to the number of elements in *rng*) the sample is without repetitions.

The second function is:

```
def getDates(dat, n):
    td1d = pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')
    # Date ranges
    rng1 = pd.Series(pd.date_range(dat - td1d * 30, dat - td1d * 11, freq='D'))
    rng2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range(dat - td1d * 10, dat - td1d * 2, freq='D'))
    # Numbers of dates
    n2 = int(round(n * 0.7))
    n1 = n - n2
    return pd.concat([getSample(rng1, n1), getSample(rng2, n2)])\
        .sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

It:

- Generates both date ranges *[d-30:d-11]* and *[d-10:d-2]*.
- Computes both numbers of elements to take from each range.
- Gets samples from both ranges (of required size), concatenates them,
  sorts and returns the result.

And the last function, generating "replicated rows" for the current row, is:

```
def repl(row):
    dat = row.Date_1
    cnt = row['count']
    return pd.DataFrame({'date_1': dat, 'count': cnt, 'date_2': getDates(dat, cnt)})
```

Now the last thing to do is to apply this function and conctenate results:

```
df2 = pd.concat(df1.sort_values('Date_1').\
    apply(repl, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Note: In cases when the number of dates from *[d-10:d-2]* range exceeds the
number of dates available, the dates are **with** repetitions.

## Edit following comment as of *21:48:25Z*

Your conception failed: Take e.g. row for *2019-09-28* (**30** rows required).
From *[d-10 : d-2]* range there should be taken 21 dates.

But because there are only **9 dates** there, then:

- we can take only **9** from this range,
- so remaining **21** dates should be taken from the second range
  (*[d-30 : d-11]*).

But this range contains **only 20** dates, so it is impossible to take
**21** dates from there (without repetitions).

Conclusion: Your requirements are exagerated.

**One more remark:**

Actually the fact that this task is impossible can be seen form
the following observation:

The date range *[d-30 : d-2]* contains **29** dates.
So do not expect that from this pool there can be taken
**30 different dates**, regardless of division between the 2 sub-ranges.

Comment: @Valdo_Bo Thank you for your answer, however, I do not understand why the dates are with repitions?

Comment: Take row for date *28/09/2019*. There should be total 30 dates, i.e.: 21 from the range *[d-10 : d-2]*.
But this range contains only **9** dates, so it is impossible to create a sample of **21** dates
without repetitions.

Comment: in that case, we pick all the values in range1 and then left values to be taken from range_2.

Comment: did you check this?

Comment: But this way you violate the principle that **70 %** of rows should have *date_2* from *[d-10 : d-2]* range.

Comment: true that, but we donot want to have the repititive values in the dataset. we want each date_1,date_2 values to be unique.